# jquery ui dialog will not reopen once closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement a jquery ui dialog. Using [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/N7PRp/) as a base, I've succeeded. But I would rather use elements' classes instead of IDs. I therefore modified the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_shipping_address").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).parents('.shipping_sector')); //correctly returns the parent fieldset
        $(this).parents('.shipping_sector').find(".shipping_dialog").dialog();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The dialog works the first time, but once it is closed, it will not open again. Whereas it works as expected in the source example. How have I damaged it?

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufaxop/1/edit)

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Do u remove it from the DOM ?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Just a side note be careful of using console.log. Not all browsers (ie for example) automatically bind the console to the browser unless you open the developer tools. This has caused me to have an error before. It's usually a good idea to do the following: `if(window.console && window.console.log)` before trying to write to the console to avoid errors in terribly built browsers like Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm using chrome. And I always make sure to take out any console calls before I go live with something. I appreciate the heads up though, thanks!

Comment: If `console` litter becomes an issue, [**andlog**](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/andlog) is a good solution. It creates a "dummy" console object with normal console methods but only ifit finds a `truthy` value in `localStorage.debug` and the console object exists. It allows you to leave the `console.log()` entries in your code without worries they are causing issue. You only see the log output if the console object exists and you have explicitly set `localStorage.debug = true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way jQuery dialogs work is that they take the HTML for the dialog out of the current location in the DOM and place a new `div` at the bottom of the DOM. When you open your dialog your new location is defined as seen below.

therefore your HTML is not where it was and your selector using `find` is not going to find anything.

You have to either use `id` or the class name directly but if you got multiple elements with that class you are better of using identifiers.

What we do in our project we craft a new div with an id specifically for the dialog, then we know which one it is. You can the either place your actual content into the new container or `clone()` it and place it inside. Similar to this:

```
var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog-container"></div>')
var $content = $(this).parents('.shipping_sector').find(".shipping_dialog");

var $clonedContent = $(this).parents('.shipping_sector').find(".shipping_dialog").clone() // use clone(true, true) to include bound events.

$dialog.append($content); // or $dialog.append($clonedContent);

$dialog.dialog();
```

But that means you also have to slightly restructure your code to deal with that.

In addition when the dialog is destroyed it does not move the HTML back again where it found it so we manually have to put it back. Mind you we are using jQuery 1.7 and I don't know if that is still the same issue in 1.9.

Dialogs are quite tricky to deal with but if you use something similar to the above whereby you create a custom `div` for example and give it a unique id you have a lot of freedom.

#### What your new HTML looks like when dialog is opened:

```
<div style="display: block; z-index: 1003; outline: 0px; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 300px; top: 383px; left: 86px;"
class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable"
tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-1">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-1">Contact form</span>
        <a
        href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
            </a>
    </div>
    <div class="shipping_dialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 91.03125px; height: auto;"
    scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
        <p>appear now</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se"
    style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. so how can I have a page with multiple dialogs without specific IDs, if I can't find the "nearest" one by using the `parents('.adf').find('.dialog').dialog();` approach? Thanks!

Comment: @thomas: I added some options. I would not be able to give you a copy-paste solution as some restructuring would be required and I don't know all of your code. In general you can create a temporary div, give it a unique identifier and once opened use that container as a reference for the current dialog content. One dialog destroy the div is simply gone again and you can re-create it as needed. There is many other ways of doing it but either one needs to be able to deal with the DOM changes and the way jQuery moves the HTML around...and the lack of moving it back,etc..

Answer (score 3):

You're current code is :

```
$(".OpenDialogOnClick").dialog();
```

And just change it to:

```
$(".OpenDialogOnClick").clone().dialog();
```

Voila, you're HTML will never be destroyed / deleted again :)

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the parenting structure for the dialog has changed.

Try changing it to

```
//jquery dialog functions
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_shipping_address").click(function() {
        //console.log($(this).parents('.shipping_sector'));
        $(".shipping_dialog").dialog();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufaxop/6/edit)

Comment: This works with one item but as the OP is wanting to use classes over IDs one would presume there will be many controls with the 'shipping_dialog' and 'add_shipping_address' classes.

Comment: @areich That's exactly right. This approach assumes a class with only one member. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind creating a new dialog every time, you can essentially destroy your dialog and move the contents back to its previous location. That way on the next click, the process will repeat itself.

```
//jquery dialog functions
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_shipping_address").click(function() {
        var sector = $(this).parents('.shipping_sector');
        sector.find(".shipping_dialog").dialog({
            close: function(event, ui) 
            { 
                $(event.target).dialog('destroy');
                $(event.target).appendTo(sector);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufaxop/13/edit)